# Jquery get the selection option in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select a certain value in my dropdown via jquery..I tried this..

```
$("#membershiptype").val(1).selected;
```

it doesnt work..I am clearly over my head here as I am inexperience in jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an option by index, you can do this :

```
$("#membershiptype").get(0).selectedIndex=1;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dNREG/)

To select an option by value (the content of the option), you may use this :

```
$("#membershiptype").val('B');​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/s5Lbx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the val() to the option value you want to be selected.

```
$('#membershiptype').val(valueToBeSelected);
```